# WPF FileDrop Event: just allow a specific file extension

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a WPF Control and I want to drop a specific file from my desktop to this control. This is not a heavy part but I would like to check the file extension to allow or disallow the dropping. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox AllowDrop="True" DragOver="lbx1_DragOver" 
                                                      Drop="lbx1_Drop"></ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Let's assume you want to allow only C# files:

```
private void lbx1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   bool dropEnabled = true;
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, true))
   {
      string[] filenames = 
                       e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

      foreach (string filename in filenames)
      {
         if(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename).ToUpperInvariant() != ".CS")
         {
            dropEnabled = false;
    break;
         }
       }
   }
   else
   {
      dropEnabled = false;
   }

   if (!dropEnabled)
   {
      e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
  e.Handled = true;
   }            
}


private void lbx1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] droppedFilenames = 
                        e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! I'll just add that to prevent some side effects of flashing cursor when you move over children of the control you're dropping onto, you can add this:  DragEnter="lbx1_DragOver" in order for the check to be made on the DragEnter event as well as on the DragOver.