# Windows Forms: how to drag and drop a .xml file on a TextBox?

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Forms TextBox in which I want to allow the user to drag and drop a file from Windows Explorer.
I would like to allow only for dropping an .xml file (path) on the TextBox.
The way of testing the file format to be dropped, on the DragEnter event, is:

```
private void DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
  else
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

The DataFormats above doesn't contain Xml. If I use DataFormats.FileDrops, I allow any types of files to be dropped, as far as I understood.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want to know if a file format is XML? By the file extension? (unreliable, and possibly not even useful at all in your case) by the file contents? (You'd need to parse the contents to do that)

Comment: That's really part of my concern, Andrew Barber, since I wish there was a way of guaranteeing that the format of the dropped file was XML. If there is not such a way, maybe the only alternative is parsing the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check the `DataFormats.FileDrop` then get the file name(s) and verify the file extension, you can then set the `DragDropEffects` as you wish depending on how many files are dropped and their extension (in your case only 1 and xml file extension).

check this answer with a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/736883/559144

Comment: Great! The example you referred to helped a lot in making it work. Thanks!