# WPF FileDragOver Event: just allow a specific file extension Error

Tags: c#

**I copied this code from here:**
I have a problem on file dragover

[Copy From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724774/wpf-filedrop-event-just-allow-a-specific-file-extension)

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox AllowDrop="True" DragOver="lbx1_DragOver" 
                                                      Drop="lbx1_Drop"></ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**Let's assume you want to allow only C# files:**

```
private void lbx1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   bool dropEnabled = true;
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, true))
   {
      string[] filenames = 
                       e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

      foreach (string filename in filenames)
      {
         if(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename).ToUpperInvariant() != ".CS")
         {
            dropEnabled = false;
    break;
         }
       }
   }
   else
   {
      dropEnabled = false;
   }

   if (!dropEnabled)
   {
      e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
  e.Handled = true;
   }            
}


private void lbx1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] droppedFilenames = 
                        e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
}
```

But I want to use multiple extension here:
How can?

Like something:

```
 if(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename).ToUpperInvariant() != ".mp3,.mp4,.mkv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var allowedExtensions = new [] { ".MP3", ".MP4", ".MKV" };

//  If All of the filename extensions are contained in allowedExtensions, 
//  set dropEnabled to true. 

dropEnabled = filenames.All(fn =>
        allowedExtensions.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fn).ToUpperInvariant())
    );
```

Here's a version that takes up more space but it's a little easier to understand:

```
var allowedExtensions = new [] { ".MP3", ".MP4", ".MKV" };

foreach (var fn in filenames)
{
    var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fn).ToUpperInvariant();

    if (!allowedExtensions.Contains(ext))
    {
        dropEnabled = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

This question has nothing to do with WPF; it's a C# question.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother